# Maintaining state between different form submit

Tags: java, web-applications

Let say we have "form1" in "Page1.jsp" and "form2" in "page2.jsp".

Steps are:

1. Submit form1.
2. We get the input text field value "t1"  in "page2.jsp" and
3. Then use hidden field in "form 2" to pass this "t1" value to same  "page2.jsp" or "page3.jsp".
4. Submit "form2".
5. Get the same value "t1" by accessing hidden field name on the page where form 2 redirects.It can   be same page or some other page say "page3.jsp".

Hence it is an easy way to pass information between pages. Here see the difference where only hidden field works but session can't do. If  hidden field is used to pass this "t1" value to same  "page2.jsp". It means If we redirect the form 2 to same page2 i.e. Steps are:

Let say we have "form1" in "Page1.jsp" and "form2" in "page2.jsp."

1. Submit "form1".
2. We get the input text field value "t1"  in "page2.jsp" and
3. Then create a  session to hold this "t1" value.
4. Submit "form2".
5. Now if "form 2" redirects to "page3.jsp"  then we can easily get session value but if "form 2"   redirects to "page2.jsp" (redirects to the same page) then the session value is empty.

Why we could not get the session value on the same page where hidden field can? Please tolerate me for this long question. But I want to know the concept behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the session can get value on the same page. Sessions reside on server-side.

JSP container creates on `jsession_id` for each visitor and puts this information in response (via query string or cookie). For each request, the browser sends back the `jsession_id` information. Back to server side, there's a map with jsession_id as key and session as value. JSP or servlet can so access information within this object.

However, of course, value in `t1`, such as your example, should be sent to server-side and put in session to be recovered in a future use.

[See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)